# Application object is not defined after closing and opening again in UFT

Tags: hp-uft

Application object is not defined after closing and opening again. There are no runtime errors but all actions performed under object in application can not force it to act, e.g.:

```
workersJavaTree.Select("Node1;Node1.2")
```

the object `workersJavaTree` does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reopening the object in application UFT object should be reinitialized:

```
workersJavaTree.init()
```

And then all actions under the object are performed well.

**Hierarchical structure while initializing**

If there are several objects that are reloaded/reopened (e.g. reload a form with several fields & controls) you should `init()` the top-most one. And all children after that are available. Chech the next picture:

[image]

You should only do `object_3.init()`, after that you can start with `object_5.doSomething()`.

**Timer after initialization**

Sometimes object is not seen right after the initialization, so I have created custom `init()` function with check that object already exists:

```
' customized initialization of reloaded/reopened object
Function customizedInit(object, timeToWait, details)
    object.init()
    isInitialized = False
    If NOT(object.Exist(timeToWait)) Then
        ReportAndLogFailWithScreenshot "Initialized object was not found in " & timeToWait & " seconds", details
        isInitialized = False
    Else
        isInitialized = True
    End If

    customizedInit = isInitialized
End Function
```

Attention: in this function you should use the object that would be used in action not the top-most.